Raspberry PI 5 - No Display on TV only
I have a Samsung 32 inches monitor (Viewfinity Ls32A600Nwmxue) and a Samsung 55 inches 4K QLED TV (QA55Q70BAUXSA). On my Raspberry PI I installed Batocera and on another sd card Raspbian.
When connect RP5 to monitor, display works without issues. But when I connect that to the TV, the TV says that the device may be turned off. I have tried with different RP5's and it's all the same. When I ejected the SD card, I connected directly without an SD card, I can see the screen so I am sure either RP or TV port has no issues.
On my Batocera image, the config.txt was initially below:
arm_boost=1
arm_64bit=1
kernel=boot/linux
initramfs boot/initrd.lz4
dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d,cma-512

dtparam=krnbt=on

[Overclock]
over_voltage=

I tried also
arm_boost=1
arm_64bit=1
kernel=boot/linux
initramfs boot/initrd.lz4
dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d,cma-512

# Force HDMI output
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
hdmi_drive=2
hdmi_group=1
hdmi_mode=16 
 
config_hdmi_boost=4
hdmi_ignore_cec_init=1
 
dtparam=krnbt=on

Also I tried with hdmi_mode=4, hdmi_mode=31, config_hdmi_boost=4, config_hdmi_boost=9 and hdmi_safe=1
None of them worked.
I also tried with different ports and different cables / adapters. Works only when SD card is detached.
I tested with stock Raspbian OS as well. No differences. Works only on monitor, not the TV.
How can I get display on my TV? Which parameters I need to use?
